# Minimax algorithm with/without Alpha-Beta Pruning

Tags: algorithm, minimax

Can the minimax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning yield a different answer than minimax without pruning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) says:

> Alpha-beta pruning is a sound optimization in that it does not change the score of the result of the algorithm it optimizes.

So, the **value** does not change. But the concrete realization of it can be different.

Comment: What do you mean by concrete realization?

Comment: When there are different nodes that all have the same value as the minimum the search might yield a different one. I'm not sure whether there are variants where this can not happen.

Answer (score 1):

Part (a): Apply MiniMax Algorithm without using Alpha Beta Pruning on the following tree and find the respective values of empty Nodes.
05 Marks

Part (b): Apply MiniMax Algorithm with Alpha Beta Pruning on the following tree and find the respective values of empty Nodes. Draw a line cut on the edges which are pruned. 
15 Marks